# The process of transforming a normal vector from world space into the local space of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

What's the process of transforming a normal vector from world space to the local space of a matrix transform?

Comment: No it's maths related, I'm just trying to figure out the process, in terms of finding the inverse of a matrix and things like that.

Comment: I am applying it in a 3d graphics situation but I don't have access to any opengl or directx APIs, nothing besides basic 3D math APIs.